# Continuous function between discrete topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I have read on Wikipedia that:

If a set $X$ is given the discrete topology (in which every subset is open), all functions
$${\displaystyle f\colon X\rightarrow T}$$

to any topological space $T$ are continuous.

Why is this the case? I am particularly interested in the case when $T$ is also a discrete topology.

Comment: $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $T$. If $X$ has the discrete topology, *every* subset of $X$ is open in $X$, so continuity of $f$ is automatic.

Comment: The definition of continuity requires the inverse image of an open set in $T$ is open in $X$. Since $X$ has discrete topology, every set is open. So the condition is automatically satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

A map $f:X\to T $ is continuous if for every open set $U \subset T $, the set $f^{-1}(U) $ of all $x\in X $ so that $f (x) \in U $ is open. If $X$ has the discrete topology, the every subset is open, so $f^{-1}(U) $ is open. Therefore $f $ is continuous.